# Applying currency change from currency dropdown menu to the rest of my budgeting app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a JS project for an online course where I am creating a budgeting app

I have the following components as part of my app

1. Budget
2. Remaining
3. Spent so far
4. Allocated Budget
5. Change Allocation

I was tasked with creating a 6th component for the app "CurrencyDropdown" to house the different currency options to choose from. I have done this.

```
// CurrencyDropdown.js


import React, { useState } from 'react';
 
const CurrencyDropdown = () => {
const [selectedCurrency, setSelectedCurrency] = useState('$'); // Default currency

const handleCurrencyChange = (event) => {
setSelectedCurrency(event.target.value);
};
return (
<div className='alert alert-primary'>
<label htmlFor="currency">Currency:</label>
<select id="currency" value={selectedCurrency} onChange={handleCurrencyChange}>
<option value="$">$ Dollar</option>
<option value="£">£ Pound</option>
<option value="€">€ Euro</option>
<option value="₹">₹ Rupee</option> 
{/* Add more currency options as needed */}
</select>
</div>
);
};
export default CurrencyDropdown;
```

The next task is to add code to the project so that when you change the currency from the `CurrencyDropdown`, the currency displayed on all the other components across the app change to match the selected currency. That is where I got stuck.

I tried to create a new JS component `CurrencyContext`:

```
// CurrencyContext.js

import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const CurrencyContext = createContext();

export const CurrencyProvider = ({ children }) => {
const [selectedCurrency, setSelectedCurrency] = useState('USD');

const changeCurrency = (currency) => {
setSelectedCurrency(currency);
};

return (
<CurrencyContext.Provider value={{ selectedCurrency, changeCurrency }}>
      {children}
</CurrencyContext.Provider>
);
};

export const useCurrency = () => {
return useContext(CurrencyContext);
};
```

I do not know how or where to apply this component to effect the change to the rest of my app.

Comment: Are you using any state management in your app?

Comment: Yes, state management is included in the app.

Comment: You can create a reducer function to update the selected currency value. And register `useSelector(state=>state.something.something)` in all the components where you want to use the selected value. Basically `state.something.something` is nothing but the path to the property that you will be updating with the help of reducer.

Answer (score 1):

To use the `CurrencyProvider` and `useCurrency` the rest of the app, you need to wrap your entire application or the relevant part of it with the `CurrencyProvider`. This will make the `selectedCurrency` and `changeCurrency` available to all components nested within it.

```
//index.js

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <CurrencyProvider>
      <App />
    </CurrencyProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Like this wrap the entire app with the `currencyProvider` and this will effect the change throughout the app.

Answer (score 0):

To use your `CurrencyContext.js`, wrap your application with `<CurrencyProvider/>`

Example

```
<CurrencyProvider>
  <CurrencyDropdown />
  <Remaining />
</CurrencyProvider>
```

This will allow other components to use your currency context. Note that all components that uses the `CurrencyContext` should be children of `CurrencyProvider`

You may now use `selectedCurrency` and `changeCurrency` in `CurrencyDropdown.js`

```js
// CurrencyDropdown.js

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useCurrency } from "./CurrencyProvider";

const CurrencyDropdown = () => {
  const { selectedCurrency, changeCurrency } = useCurrency();

  const handleCurrencyChange = (event) => {
    changeCurrency(event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="alert alert-primary">
      <label htmlFor="currency">Currency:</label>
      <select
        id="currency"
        value={selectedCurrency}
        onChange={handleCurrencyChange}
      >
        <option value="$">$ Dollar</option>
        <option value="£">£ Pound</option>
        <option value="€">€ Euro</option>
        <option value="₹">₹ Rupee</option>
        {/* Add more currency options as needed */}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
export default CurrencyDropdown;
```

And in other components such as `Remaining.js`, you can now use `selectedCurrency`

```js
// Remaining.js

import React from "react";
import { useCurrency } from "./CurrencyProvider";

const Remaining = () => {
  const currencyRemaining = 100;
  const { selectedCurrency } = useCurrency();
  return (
    <div>
      Remaining:
      {selectedCurrency} {currencyRemaining}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Remaining;
```